# Hierarchy Structure of Themes in Google BigQuery GDELT GKG 2.0

Tags: google-bigquery, hierarchy, gdelt

We're using Google bigquery to analyze the GDELT GKG 2.0 dataset and would like to better understand how to query based on themes (or V2Themes). More specifically we are interested in the hierarchy structure (how hierarchies are created) of the Themes. For example, we want to find out the hierarchy structure of all the themes related to Natural disasters and the code yields the following output

[image: themes_code_output]

Apparently some hierarchy levels are separated by underscores while others are not. Also granularities of hierarchies are a bit messy which makes the structure not quite clear.

Do you happen to have any sources/information on how these themes are structured (hierarchy levels)?